# Can I create a custom error at Cypress.io?

Tags: cypress

I have tried all sorts of techniques but none create a custom error message.
Has anyone managed to crack the problem?

```js
const { statusCode, body } = serverRequest.response;
if (statusCode !== 200 || statusCode !== 201) {
  const { errorKey, subErrorKey, errorMsg } = body?.error || {};

  Cypress.runner.stop();
  throw new Error(`${errorKey}->${subErrorKey}-${errorMsg}`);
}
```

Comment: That one works for me. `throw new Error(`${errorKey}->${subErrorKey}-${errorMsg}`);` What error do you get. May be `Cypress.runner.stop();` this line is the problem

Comment: Yes @RosenMihaylov is right, when you call `Cypress.runner.stop()` it will do that, just stop, and never execute your `throw`.

Answer (score 1):

`throw new Error(...)` by itself will stop the current current test, or all tests if it's in a `before()` or `beforeEach()`.

```js
before(() => {
  ...
  const { statusCode, body } = serverRequest.response;
  if (statusCode !== 200 || statusCode !== 201) {
    const { errorKey, subErrorKey, errorMsg } = body?.error || {};
    throw new Error(`${errorKey}->${subErrorKey}-${errorMsg}`);
  }
  ...
})
```

Cypress will stop with something like "because the error occurred in 'before()' we will not perform any tests".

Answer (score 0):

Throwing the new error is enough to stop the case. I think your code just needs to remove `Cypress.runner.stop();`, because it shuts everything down.

```
const { statusCode, body } = serverRequest.response;
                if (statusCode !== 200 || statusCode !== 201) {
                    const { errorKey, subErrorKey, errorMsg } = body?.error || {};

                   
                    throw new Error(`${errorKey}->${subErrorKey}-${errorMsg}`);
                }
```